# How to prove that $S_{v_{j}}$ can be represented at least two times terms of $a$, $a+d$, $a+2d$, and $a+3d$?

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that  $S_{v_{j}}$ can be represented at at least two times?
$S_{v_{j}}=(a+d)+\dfrac{j-1}{3}(a+3d)           \qquad \text{if $j=1 \mod 3$}$, $ gcd(a,d)=1$, where $j< a.$
Can anybody help? Thanks